# How to implement order by in Django Query?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have simple Django Query like this:

```
session_info = Session.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
```

I want to order the data where `make_default = 1` Now, the data are listed from top to bottom. Now, I want the data with `make_default = 1` to be at the top.

Comment: Your result will only contain rows which have `make_default=1` as you have it in filter condition. What is the field with which you want ordering. "Now, I want the data with make_default = 1 to be at the top". Every row will have make_default=1 since you have it in filter, so this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry posted the wrong query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kind of unclear, but based on your comment, it sounds like you want `.order_by('-make_default')`.  Assuming you have a number of make_default=0 items that you want to appear after the make_default=1 items, that should suffice.  The '-' reverses the order.

Comment: Yes, it indeed suffice. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

```
session_info = Session.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id, make_default=1).order_by('-user_id')
```